# How to avoid too many connections on spring+hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I´ve my hibernate configuration inside my spring-context, but after a little time of use I´m getting the too many connections error. Here is my code:
Spring context:

```
 <!-- Beans Declaration -->
 <bean id="Usuarios" class="com.proximate.model.Usuarios"/>
<!-- Service Declaration -->
<bean id="UsuariosService" class="com.proximate.service.UsuariosService">
    <property name="usuariosDAO" ref="UsuariosDAO" />
</bean>
<!-- DAO Declaration -->
<bean id="UsuariosDAO" class="com.proximate.dao.UsuariosDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
 <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />   
        <property name="password" value="password" />   
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" /> 
    </bean> 
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.proximate.model.Usuarios</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>                         
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

and here is how I use my session factory inside my dao:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

Query query = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT ID FROM usuarios");
Integer cantidad = new Integer(((BigInteger) query.uniqueResult()).intValue());
```

Why is my code opening so many connections. I heard that using a HibernateUtil class to load a session after logging might be what I need, but how do you implement it when using spring??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about hibernate itself, but i think closing the session might help.
That's how JPAs `EntityManager` works - you have to close it to close underlaying connection.

Comment: i tought spring did that automatically?

Comment: It does, but you need to wrap your method with `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hibernate query is global?  I would guess the cause is probably because it is not contained in a method with a transactional annotation around it.